# ASP.NET Generic method to mock EF6 DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, generics, moq

In my ASP.NET MVC5 web-app I'm using the EF (Model-first) for my database-communication. For unit-testing purposes, I created a generic method to generate Mock database sets. Unfortunately, I am unable to mock all the methods because when `.Where()`, `.Any()` and `.Find()` are used in my tested code, an exception is thrown. Can anyone help me on this? My code is below.
Unittest:

```
[TestClass()]
public class MessagingServiceTests
{
    Mock<BoatstersEntitiesContainer> _mockContext;
    MessagingService _service;
    string _connectionId;
    Guid _userId;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _userId = Guid.Parse("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123412344142");
        _connectionId = "abc123";


        // Setup entities
        User user = new User { Id = _userId, CustomerId = 1 };
        Customer customer = new Customer { Id = 1, User = user, FirstName = "TestFirstName" };
        user.Customer = customer;
        Customer boatOwnerCustomer = new Customer { Id = 2, FirstName = "BoatOwner" };
        Boat boat = new Boat { Id = 1, Customer = boatOwnerCustomer, CustomerId = boatOwnerCustomer.Id };
        boatOwnerCustomer.Boats.Add(boat);


        // Init mocksets
        var userMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<User> { user });
        var customerMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<Customer> { customer, boatOwnerCustomer });
        var conversationMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<Conversation>());
        var messageMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<Message>());
        var boatMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<Boat> { boat });
        var messagingHubConnectionMockSet = MockDbSet.Build(new List<MessagingHubConnection>());


        // Setup mockcontext
        _mockContext = new Mock<BoatstersEntitiesContainer>();
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(userMockSet.Object);
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Customers).Returns(customerMockSet.Object);
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Conversations).Returns(conversationMockSet.Object);
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Messages).Returns(messageMockSet.Object);
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Boats).Returns(boatMockSet.Object);
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.MessagingHubConnections).Returns(messagingHubConnectionMockSet.Object);


        // Start service
        _service = new MessagingService(_mockContext.Object, _userId);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void When_PartnerConnected_IsTrue()
    {
        Conversation conversation = new Conversation {
            Id = 1,
            Boat = _mockContext.Object.Boats.First(b => b.Id.Equals(1)),
            BoatId = _mockContext.Object.Boats.First(b => b.Id.Equals(1)).Id
        };
        conversation.Customers.Add(_mockContext.Object.Customers.First(b => b.Id.Equals(1)));
        conversation.Customers.Add(_mockContext.Object.Customers.First(b => b.Id.Equals(2)));

        MessagingHubConnection connection = new MessagingHubConnection
        {
            Id = 1,
            Connected = true,
            ConnectionId  = "abc123",
            Conversation = conversation,
            ConversationId = 1,
            Customer = _mockContext.Object.Customers.First(b => b.Id.Equals(2)),
            CustomerId = 2
        };
        conversation.MessagingHubConnections.Add(connection);

        _mockContext.Object.MessagingHubConnections.Add(connection);
        _mockContext.Object.Conversations.Add(conversation);

        var result = _service.IsPartnerConnected();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);

        // Clean up
        _mockContext.Object.Conversations.RemoveRange(_mockContext.Object.Conversations);
        _mockContext.Object.MessagingHubConnections.RemoveRange(_mockContext.Object.MessagingHubConnections);
    }
}
```

Generic mockset creator:

```
public static class MockDbSet
{
    public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> Build<TEntity>(List<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
    {
        var queryable = data.AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        mockSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback<TEntity>(data.Add);

        return mockSet;
    }
}
```

Messagingservice (which is being tested)

```
public class MessagingService : BaseRepository<Conversation>
{
    private readonly Customer _customer;
    private MessagingHubConnection _connection;

    public MessagingService(BoatstersEntitiesContainer context, Guid userId) : base(context)
    {
        Context = context;
        _customer = Context.Customers.First(c => c.User.Id == userId);
    }


    public bool IsPartnerConnected()
    {
        // Check if partner is connected
        return Context.MessagingHubConnections.Any(c => c.ConversationId.Equals(_connection.ConversationId) && c.Customer.Id != _customer.Id && c.Connected);
    }
}
```

In MessagingService.IsPartnerConnected(), the following exception is thrown:

> Test Name:    When_PartnerConnected_IsTrue
>   Test FullName:  Boatsters.Sunshine.UnitTests.MessagingServiceTests.When_PartnerConnected_IsTrue
>   Test Source:    C:\Users\Jelle\Source\Repos\Boatsters.Sunshine\Boatsters.Sunshine.UnitTests\MessagingServiceUnitTest.cs : line 94
>   Test Outcome:   Failed
>   Test Duration:  0:00:00,0289022
>   Result StackTrace:
>   bij lambda_method(Closure , MessagingHubConnection )
>      bij System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      bij lambda_method(Closure )
>      bij System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor`1.Execute()
>      bij System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
>      bij System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>      bij Boatsters.Services.MessagingService.IsPartnerConnected() in C:\Users\Jelle\Source\Repos\Boatsters.Sunshine\Boatsters.Services\MessagingService.cs:line 156
>      bij xxx.MessagingServiceTests.When_PartnerConnected_IsTrue() in C:\xxx\MessagingServiceUnitTest.cs:line 118
>   Result Message: 
>   Test method
>   xxx.UnitTests.MessagingServiceTests.When_PartnerConnected_IsTrue threw exception: 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I've removed the `asp.net` tag (because in the end it isn't a asp.net question). I've added the `moq` tag (because you shuld be using it, right? the `Mock<>` class is from `moq` I think)

Comment: What is the exception. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem and also the desired behavior. How are you applying the code above in relation to what you are trying to test.

Comment: Based on review of `MessagingService` not seeing where `_connection` is assigned a value. Looks like that is what is `null` when the method under test is called based on stack trace `lambda_method(Closure , MessagingHubConnection )`

Comment: @Nkosi Oh wow thanks! This was actually pretty stupid.. I might have to do some refactoring..

Comment: @JelleKerkstra I've updated answer to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on review of `MessagingService`, it is not immediately apparent where `_connection` is assigned a value. Looks like that is what is `null` when the method under test is called based on stack trace `lambda_method(Closure , MessagingHubConnection )`

Also from past experiences with Moq and `DbSet<>`, this line needs to updated so that multiple calls can be made to the data source.

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
```

Change the `.Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator())` to return a Func

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator()); //<-- Note change here.
```

The original will return the same enumerator for every call which can only be enumerated once and may cause issues. Using the `Func` will allow a fresh enumerator to be return on every call to allow for multiple passes on the data source.